K8 GCE deployment cluster failed to initalize after kube-up.sh
Running into a issue after running kube-up.sh script on Ubuntu 22.04. From what I can tell, after running kube-up.sh it creates my master & worker needs in Google Cloud successfully, but presents an error timeout before finishing installation shown below:
Trying to find master named 'kubernetes-master' Looking for address 'kubernetes-master-ip' Using master: kubernetes-master (external IP: 34.42.x.x; internal IP: (not set)) Waiting up to 300 seconds for cluster initialization.
This will continually check to see if the API for kubernetes is reachable. This may time out if there was some uncaught error during start up.
...........................................Cluster failed to initialize within 300 seconds. Last output from querying API server follows:

    Trying 34.42.x.x:443...
    Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds
    Closing connection 0 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds

When i utilize "bash -x source kube-up.sh" to run the same script & find the reason it fails during the 300 second initialization period, I see that it is trying to do curls to the specified location below but fails which gives the connection timed out above:
curl -vsS --cacert /tmp/tmp.7UPPc2xx7M/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/ca.crt -H 'Authorization: Bearer nkTxhPLM9WSHLZ6VWkUfxNH0gnGef6Ih' --max-time 5 --fail 'https://34.42.x.x/api/v1/pods?limit=100'

This is also what is in my kubeconfig file:
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
authentication:
  webhook:
    enabled: false
authorization:
  mode: AlwaysAllow
enableServer: false
podCIDR: 10.42.0.0/24
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
staticPodURL: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/google-container-manifest
staticPodURLHeader:
  Metadata-Flavor: [Google]
cgroupDriver: systemd

I have tried permitting https locally & in the cloud firewall thinking maybe curl was being dropped on 443. Have tried changing service account permissions within the cloud. Have tried re-deploying cluster.
